# Como puedo consultar una tercera tabla con ORM de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, orm

Actualmente la consulta me funciona hasta la seguda tabla donde logro consultar las empresas y las categorias, pero no he logrado consultar la tercera tabla conservando la agrupacion, cuando realizo la tercer consulta (foreach 3), solo muestra los datos como la imagen 2 y  en las demas empresas solo deja las categorias sin productos.

Busco que la consulta muestre los productos agrupados por categorias y agrupados por empresa

Esta es la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Esto de anidar foreachs, no es nada optimo, lo veo mas como una practica, habría que realizar una consulta un poco mas compleja con joins etc etc, pero para practicar intenta con algo así.

```
foreach($companies as $company){
    echo $company->name;
    foreach($company->categories as $category){
        echo $category->name;
        $products = Product::where('company_id', $company->id)->where('category_id', $category->id)->get();
        foreach($products as $product){
            echo $product->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola!, primero que todo muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme, ya lo intente, el resultado funciono similar a como la tenia, la diferencia es que ya no se repite los productos en cada categoría, pero sigue sin mostrarme los productos de cada empresa, solo muestra los productos de la primera, es un proyecto personal, o como me recomiendas hacer la consulta?, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Despues de mucho tiempo e investigacion tengo la solucion se las dejo por si a alguien mas le sirve

```
        $companies2 = Product::join('companies', 'products.company_id','=', 'companies.id')
        ->select('products.name','products.coast','companies.name as comp','products.sale_price','products.category_id')
        ->where('companies.id', '=', 1)
        ->get();

    foreach($companies2 as $company){
        echo '<p>'.$company->comp. ' - '.$company->name.' - '.$company->coast.' - '.$company->category->name.'<p>';  
    }
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]